# $\mathbb{F}_q(t)$ vs $\mathbb{F}_q[t]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, notation, finite-fields, function-fields

I am having certain troubles understanding certain manuscript. What is the difference between
$$
\mathbb{F}_q(t) \quad \text{ and } \quad \mathbb{F}_q[t]?
$$

Comment: Typically the difference between $k[t]$ and $k(t) is that the first denotes the polynomial ring in t with coefficients in k, and the latter denotes the field of fraction in t (k is a field).

Comment: By the field of fraction you mean $A/B$, where $A, B$ are polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: Yes - with the condition that $B\neq 0$, and $\frac{A}{B}$ is in lowest terms.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Also about the notation $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ (polynomials in $i$) is also $ \{a+ib, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $i$ which is $ \{a+ib, (a,b) \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ again.

Answer (score 2):

For any field $\Bbb K$, $\Bbb K[t]$ is the algebra of *polynomials* in the indeterminate $t$, having coefficients in the field $\Bbb K$:

$\Bbb K[t] = \left \{ \displaystyle \sum_0^n a_i t^i, \; a_i \in \Bbb K, \; 0 \le n \in \Bbb Z \right \}; \tag 1$

we note, as is well-known, that $\Bbb K[t]$ is an *integral domain*; that is, it has no zero-divisors:

$\forall a(t), b(t) \in \Bbb K[t], \; a(t) \ne 0 \ne b(t) \Longrightarrow a(t)b(t) \ne 0; \tag 2$

this follows easily from the fact that the product of the leading terms of

$a(t) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg a} a_i t^i, \; b(t) =  \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg b} b_i t^i, \tag 3$

which is

$a_{\deg a} b_{\deg b} t^{\deg a + \deg b} \ne 0, \tag 4$

since

$a_{\deg a} \ne 0 \ne b_{\deg b}, \tag 5$

by the definition of "leading term".  In fact, it is also well-known that $\Bbb K[t]$ is a *principal ideal domain*, but this need not concern us further here.

Since $\Bbb K[t]$ is an integral domain, it is possessed of well-defined field of fractions $\mathcal{Frac}(\Bbb K[t])$, which *prima facie* may be taken to be the set of quotients of elements of $\Bbb K[t]$:

$\mathcal{Frac}(\Bbb K[t]) = \left \{ \dfrac{a(t)}{b(t)}, \; a(t), 0 \ne b(t) \in 
\Bbb K[t] \right \}; \tag 6$

$\mathcal{Frac}(\Bbb K[t])$ is of course easily recognized as the field of *rational functions* in the indeterminate $t$, with coefficients in the field $\Bbb K$.

In the light of these remarks, we consider the field $\Bbb K(t)$, the *smallest field*, in the sense of set inclusion, containing both $\Bbb K$ and $t$, that is,

$\Bbb K \subset \Bbb K(t), \; t \in \Bbb K(t), \tag 7$

and therefore, since $\Bbb K(t)$ is closed under the algebraic operations addition and multiplication,

$\Bbb K[t] \subset \Bbb K(t); \tag 8$

furthermore, since $\Bbb K(t)$ is a field, it must also contain the quotients of elements of $K[t]$, that is,

$\mathcal{Frac}(\Bbb K[t]) \subset K(t) \tag 9$

as well.  Now since $K(t)$ is by definition the smallest field $K[t]$, it follows that in fact

$\mathcal{Frac}(\Bbb K[t]) = K(t), \tag{10}$

and thus $K(t)$ is in fact the field of rational functions in $t$ over $\Bbb K$.  We now see that the difference 'twixt $\Bbb K[t]$ and $\Bbb K(t)$ is concisely expressed by (10).